# JobData added to Trigger not passed to Job in Quartz

Tags: java, mongodb, quartz-scheduler

I have a durable job added to the scheduler. At the runtime, i am building a trigger using below code:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity(new TriggerKey(triggerKey))
                    .forJob(Constants.CAMPAIGN_MAILING_JOB_KEY)
                    .usingJobData("test", "test")
                    .startAt(new Date(runTime))
                    .build();
```

I then schedule this job using ,

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
```

The job is executed properly, however the Jobdata ("test" string param) is giving me null in the job. this is my job code,

```
public class CampaignMessageSendingJob implements Job{
public String campaignId;
public String messageId;

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("This JOb Was called at"+System.currentTimeMillis());

    JobKey key = jobContext.getJobDetail().getKey();
    JobDataMap map= jobContext.getMergedJobDataMap();
    System.out.println(map.getString("test")); //This is printing NULL

}

public String getCampaignId() {
    return campaignId;
}

public void setCampaignId(String campaignId) {
    this.campaignId = campaignId;
}

public String getMessageId() {
    return messageId;
}

public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
    this.messageId = messageId;
}
```

}

What am i missing here?

Using mongodb as JobStore Implementation

Answer (score 1):

String value=context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("test")

**Please try above solution**

Comment: System.out.println(jobContext.getMergedJobDataMap().getString("test")); --NULL
  System.out.println(jobContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().getString("test")); --NULL
  System.out.println(jobContext.getTrigger().getJobDataMap().getString("test"));  --NULL

Comment: context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("test")

Comment: Nope, it didnt'